How to tell TeX to avoid overfull hboxes by breaking a line?
Is there a way to tell TeX that, whenever a paragraph cannot be typeset properly, it should never produce an Overfull hbox, and break some line in the paragraph instead?
I do know about all I should do to prevent this from happening, using \emergencystretch, micro-typography, etc. I also know that I could manually add a \newline. I'm asking for a parameter that would automatically favour line breaks over overlapping lines.

(edited thanks to David Carlisle's kind answers, sorry for the bad formulation of the original question)

\sloppy will usually set parameters that achieve this (or simply setting \emergencystretch large enough)

Isn't \emergencystretch just allowing to stretch "bad" lines a bit more, without influencing what happens when a line is "really too bad"?

if \emergencystretch is \hsize then there is always enough stretch to avoid an overfull box as long as the words are short enough to get two per line with a space between. If you have a single unbreakable word (or image or whatever) that is wider than the text width you can not avoid over full boxes. As you have provided no example, and basically put a solution in the question, it's hard to answer.

It's hard to find an example (or too easy: any overfull hbox would be an example...), sorry for this. But I'm afraid my question wasn't very clear: I do not want to stretch the lines more (which would be very ugly), what I want is that when TeX can't arrange a paragraph properly, it just breaks a line somewhere. In other words, a ragged line would be the "fallback" behaviour if justifying fails.

hmm I was just posting an answer while you were making the above comment:-) I'll leave it up as it may be useful to someone, but you don't need to accept it. You might need luatex to do what you ask, I'm not sure it's possible in classic tex without adding specific markup at the optional break points.

Oooh, now I guess I see where my question was asked badly: I thought underfull hboxes were not justified... Sorry! I'm going to edit my question.

underfull means stretched more than allowed so they are almost always justified but over-stretched, to make a ragged line you typically add stretch glue to the right hand edge, and that makes the box not underfull, just visibly short.


The standard latex command would be \sloppy but often better results can be obtained just using \emergencystretch rather than adjusting \tolerance as done by \sloppy.
The first two paragraphs have overfull lines reported as
Overfull \hbox (56.6678pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 7--13
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa a
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Overfull \hbox (242.22395pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--18
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa 


The same text again after setting emergencystretch produces underfull boxes:
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 22--28
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 32--34
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

If \emergencystretch is large enough you will only get overfull boxes if there is unbreakable content that is wider than the text width.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\bigskip\noindent X\dotfill X\par\bigskip

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\bigskip\noindent X\dotfill X\par\bigskip

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

\bigskip\noindent X\dotfill X\par\bigskip
\emergencystretch\textwidth

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa


\bigskip\noindent X\dotfill X\par\bigskip

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa



\end{document}

